# Switch between hardcoded configuration and command line with argparse

Tags: python, configuration, argparse

For ease of development, I use a **hardcoded argparse configuration** in my code.

```
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    local_conf = {
        "debug": True,
        "loglevel": 2
    }

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--from_bash", action="store_true")
    parser.add_argument("--debug", action="store_true")
    parser.add_argument("--loglevel", default=5)
    conf =parser.parse_args()

    if not conf.from_bash:
        conf.__dict__ = {**conf.__dict__, **local_conf}  # merges configurations

    ....
```

I find it easier to switch on and off options by commenting them.

To execute it from script, I use an option to tell the program to ignore the hardcoded configuration : **--from_bash** here

`python main.py --from_bash --loglevel 3`

This is bug prone, if I forget the --from_bash option, I get a wrong configuration.

Is there a cleaner way to switch between a hardcoded configuration and a command line ?

Comment: Looks like your user needs to select from 3 values, `local_conf`, the `argparse` defaults, and user provided values.  Do you really need those `argparse` defaults?

Answer (score 1):

Here are two alternatives.

---

You are putting the mental load on the user to add `--from_bash` when they want their configurations obeyed. It would probably make more sense to require a special flag so that the hardcoded configurations are only used with the flag.

```
...
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--dev", action="store_true", help=argparse.SUPPRESS)  # Don't show in help message... user doesn't need to know
...

if conf.dev:
    conf.__dict__ = {**conf.__dict__, **local_conf}  # merges configurations
...
```

Now, only you as the developer need to know anything about the hard-coded configurations.

---

For an out-of-the-box approach, you can use the `argparse` ability to read configurations from a file. It takes one value per-line:

```
# Contents of configurations.txt
--debug
--loglevel
2
```

You instantiate your parser with the magic words to be able to read this configuration file:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(fromfile_prefix_chars='@')
```

You can then provide this configuration prefixed with `@`:

```
python main.py @configurations.txt
```

This would have the same effect of giving on the command-line all the options in the `configurations.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the conditional + default value in the `local_conf` values e.g:

```
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--debug", action="store_true")
    parser.add_argument("--loglevel")
    conf = parser.parse_args()
    default_level = 2
    local_conf = {
        "debug": conf.debug, # This will be False on absence of --debug 
        "loglevel": conf.loglevel if conf.loglevel else default_level
    }

    print(local_conf)
```

This for example will use `2` as a default level unless `--loglevel` is specified. When using flags (argparse's `action="store_true"`) you need to decide if you want to default to `True` or `False`

So running this without args, `local_conf` will print:

> {'debug': False, 'loglevel': 2}

Using `--loglevel 5 --debug`

> {'debug': True, 'loglevel': '5'}

Comment: Yes, tried that but it discards the possibility to set the default values in the argparse initialization, which I find worse in the end. Thanks for the idea